# Teamviewer setup is not recognising daemon

Tags: services, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I am trying to setup teamviewer's raspberry pi client on my banana pi.
As described below, even after confirming that teamviewer daemon is running, teamviewer setup still insists it is not running, despite all the evidence.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
pi@bananapi:~$ sudo teamviewer daemon start

initctl start teamviewerd
teamviewerd start/running, process 3024

pi@bananapi:~$ sudo teamviewer setup


TeamViewer daemon is not running, setup cannot continue. Please activate the TeamViewer daemon before invoking setup.

pi@bananapi:~$ sudo teamviewer daemon start

initctl start teamviewerd
teamviewerd start/running, process 3234

pi@bananapi:~$ sudo teamviewer daemon status

initctl status teamviewerd
teamviewerd start/running, process 3290

pi@bananapi:~$
```

Help to fix this issue and to continue with the setup would be ideal.
Thank you.

Comment: If memory serves me, this is a bug that was present in older versions of TV. What version are you trying to run?

Comment: https://pages.teamviewer.com/published/raspberrypi/

Comment: It is the new(ish) raspberry pi preview for armhf architectures. Version 11.X

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with the raspberry versions of TV. I'd contact TV support if I was you.

Comment: Try `sudo teamviewer --daemon enable`. If that works, please let me know and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Nope, it just claims the daemon is already running. Which it IS, it's just setup still won't realise.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem trying to run `teamviewer setup` on a graphical console on a linux desktop (using Chrome Remote Desktop).

The moment I've tried on the console directly (in my case, ssh onto the machine without any X forwarding and such), it worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me as opposed to using vnc